# How to dynamically expand segments in Greenplum DBMS

Tags: greenplum

For now, the only way I know to expand segments/hosts in greenplum is to use `gpexpand` utility. However, `gpexpand` stops the master server for quite a while(as I know) in the early expansion, and lock the table which is currently redistributing. I just want to know if there is any way that greenplum can work normally(no stop , no lock tables) when expand segments/hosts.Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Greenplum must stop during the expansion phase but after it adds more nodes/segments, the redistribution of data can be done while users are active in the database.

Alternatively, Pivotal HDB (based on Apache HAWQ) does have dynamic virtual segments that you can even control at the query level.  The optimizer controls how many segments are used for a query based on the cost of the query but you can also provide more segments to really leverage the resources available in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks. I'd attempt HDB.